# write a program that slices all symbols from start to second "C" symbol in string Variable

Tags: python-3.x

```
>>> string = "My Charamander is Preatty Cool!"
>>> cuttoff = 0
>>> newstring = ''
>>> first = string.upper().index('C')
>>> for i in range (len(string)):
    if string[i].lower() == 'c':
        cuttoff += 1
    if cuttoff == 2:
        newstring = string [first:i+1]
        break


>>> print(string)
My Charamander is Preatty Cool!
>>> print(newstring)
Charamander is Preatty C
>>>
```

well i tried my best to do this but i am pretty sure there is better way to do same thing
so any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With indexing:

```
string = "My Charamander is Preatty Cool!"
first_c_index = string.index('C')
second_c_index = string.index('C', first_c_index + 1)
print(string[first_c_index:second_c_index + 1])
# Charamander is Preatty C
```

With indexing, case insensitive version

```
string = "My Charamander is Preatty Cool!"
lower_string = string.lower()
first_c_index = lower_string.index('c')
second_c_index = lower_string.index('c', first_c_index + 1)
print(string[first_c_index:second_c_index + 1])
# Charamander is Preatty C
```

With regex

```
import re

string = "My Charamander is Preatty Cool!"
print(re.search(r'(C.*?C)', string).group(1))
# Charamander is Preatty C
```

With regex, case insensitive version

```
import re

string = "My Charamander is Preatty Cool!"
print(re.search(r'(c.*?c)', string, re.IGNORECASE).group(1))
# Charamander is Preatty C
```